# ASP MVC ChildActionOnly should have routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I don't know if this is normal but should `ChildActionOnly` methods ask for route?
For example

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult List(string countryCode, string cityName)
        {...
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

I render it like:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("List", "MyController", new { area = "MyArea", countryCode = ViewBag.CountryCode, cityName = ViewBag.CityName });}
```

In debug I get on upper line:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

**UPDATE**

```
context.MapRoute("name",
                "",
                new { area = "MyArea", controller = "MyControlelr", action = "List", countryCode = UrlParameter.Optional, cityName = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does.

All `[ChildActionOnly]` does is say that this action cannot be accessed via the URL (e.g a regular HTTP GET), rather it must be executed by `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction`. It's not a new HTTP request, but it still goes through the MVC request pipeline (controller/action selection via route values).

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing I have updated question and added example of route value. Can you tell me is this valid to have two optional parameters?

Comment: @1110 - yes it is. The values will simply be set to `string.Empty` is no values are set.